# placement new - constructor inside constructor

Tags: c++, new-operator

We have a base class A, class B derived from A. 
Now class B is allocated using placement new operator.
As a part of my code, I have added class C inside class A

Now the placement new just uses malloc of sizeof class B and does not take into account class C.
Class C constructor is called inside the Class B constructor. ( this is my suspect )

I want to know if thats correct.  Or do we add the size of class C in the placement new allocation?
if we add up the memory, how do we call the constructor for class C, it would allocate the memory again?

```
card.h {
class Card
{
private:
    char           hwModel; // HW/FW model and rev are stored in the
                            // database to detect change of card type
    char           hwRev;
    char           serialNum[EM_CARD_SERIAL_NUM_SIZE];
    char           fwModel;
    char           fwRev;
>>>>
    public:

     class IssuResource *ptrIssuResrc; 

    void *operator new(size_t size, void *objP) {size = size; return objP;};
            // overload the new operator

    void operator delete(void *objP) { objP = objP;};
            // overload the delete operator
    Card();
}


chopperCard.cpp
 // Allocate Memory and Create Card Object
     /* sa_ignore */
    buf = (UINT32 *)malloc(sizeof(CardChop));
    if (buf == NULL) {
        emLogError(EM_INTERNAL_ERROR, __FUNCTION__,
            "exit: failed to allocate %d bytes for card object\n",
            sizeof(CardChop)
        );
        exit(1);
    }

    /* sa_ignore */
    card = new (buf) CardChop(spa_issu_restart);  --> placement new 
}

Constructor for choppercard:
{
  CardChop::CardChop (boolean is_issu_set) : Card()
{
    issu_inprogress = is_issu_set;
    if (is_issu_set) {
        ISSUTRACE(4,"Issu state is SET\n");
        dev_np37xx_update_issu_state(is_issu_set);
        dev_set_issu_state(is_issu_set);
        dev_dm_issu_state(is_issu_set);
        dev_tigris_issu_state(is_issu_set);
        dev_evros_issu_state(is_issu_set);
        dev_evros1_issu_state(is_issu_set);
 >>>
     vtwin->fvt->set_gp_stat(vtwin, VTWIN_GP_STAT_APP_TRACE1,
                            CHOP_BG_INIT_FAIL);

    // init Bourget device
    initDevice((dev_object_t *)bourget);
    vtwin->fvt->set_gp_stat(vtwin, VTWIN_GP_STAT_APP_TRACE1, CHOP_BG_INIT_AFTER);
    ptrIssuResrc = new IssuResource();
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: your question is a mess, the regular "placement new" does not allocate with anything, and custom ones can't be telepathically seen

Comment: "added class C inside class A" : as a member or nested class?

Comment: @Koushik - its a public member

Comment: I should have added "compilable code". My bad.

Comment: Post the *relevant* parts of the code. We don't need to see a bunch of meaningless lines like `dev_evros_issu_state(is_issu_set);`.

Comment: On some platforms, mixing `new` and `malloc` may yield less-than-ideal results. On others, `new` is implemented by calling `malloc`. Your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 1):

Placement new will work JUST like `operator new` without placement, except that it uses the supplied address rather than allocating from the heap. Since neither forms of `operator new` will in itself call the actual constructor, the construction is exactly the same either way - the compiler calls the object constructor something like this

```
T *p = new T;
```

becomes (not valid syntax, and `T::operator new` may become `::operator new`):

```
T *p = T::operator new(sizeof(T)); p->T();
```

with placement, it's nearly the same:

```
T *p = new(somewhere) T;
```

becomes (not valid, as above):

```
T *p = T::operator new(sizeof(T), somewhere); p->T();
```

If you have something like this:

```
class C { ... };

class A 
{
   ... 
   C c; 
};

class B: public A
{
  ...
}
```

then C's constructor will be called automatically when the constructor of B is called. (And B's constructor will automatically call A's constructor)

Comment: So, we do not need explicit new operator for class C ? Like I'm doing above ?

Comment: Depends on what you are looking for - if `IssuResource` should be allocated from somewhere other than the heap, yes. Note that there is also no automatic construction for `IssuResource`, since it's a pointer to a class.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `sizeof` includes the sizes of all the bases and members. There is no other concept of size to confuse things.

It looks like the code is excessively complicated. What you are doing with `malloc` is simply reinventing the default behavior of `new`.

This does the same thing, but simpler:

```
card = new CardChop(spa_issu_restart);

if (card == NULL) {
    emLogError(EM_INTERNAL_ERROR, __FUNCTION__,
        "exit: failed to allocate %d bytes for card object\n",
        sizeof(CardChop)
    );
    exit(1);
}
```

If using the global, default `operator new`, you should also remove the `operator delete` overload.

---

In fact, the best practice with placement new is not to use `delete` at all. (Note that you have defined `operator delete` to do nothing.) The better way is to use a pseudo-destructor call, which looks like

```
card_ptr->~CardChop(); // execute destructor but no delete
free( card_ptr ); // release placement memory a la delete
```

---

Also, note that `exit` is a potentially unsafe way to terminate the program as it doesn't destroy local objects. Consider throwing an exception instead.

Comment: I tried printing the sizeof(CardChop) and it dint include the IssueResource ( its around 8MB ) .. is something wrong here ?

Comment: @FatemaMerchant Something is wrong… that is much larger than a `struct` should be.